Snowflake - SQL Query - Log in Log out - Total Hours Worked
I am trying to write a SQL query In Snowflake that would give me a single row per user per day on the total amount of hours worked for that day per user.  A user can log in and log out multiple days a week.  Each "event" is recorded per row and stored in a table based on the format below.
I am trying to calculate the hours worked between a log in and log out and total the amount of hours worked (between log ins) and collect them in a single row per day per user.  Any help is much appreciated.
Data Format:
resourcename    EventDateTime   AgentState  EventDateTimeInSeconds
Chris Medina    5/6/24 5:59 AM  Logged In   21560
Chris Medina    5/6/24 2:34 PM  Logged Out  52477
Chris Medina    5/6/24 5:35 PM  Logged In   52539
Chris Medina    5/6/24 8:36 PM  Logged Out  52581
Christie Willis 5/6/24 6:59 AM  Logged In   25184
Christie Willis 5/6/24 11:00 AM Logged Out  39618
Christie Willis 5/6/24 4:00 PM  Logged In   57610
Christie Willis 5/6/24 8:03 PM  Logged Out  72198

Not sure how to attack this issue at all.
Data Format


Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that SO is not a service to provide working code for a question that does not contain any code. Please provide what you have tried, and optimally an [example]. Please read [ask].

In Snowflake, you can use a SQL query that pairs each "Logged In" event with the next "Logged Out" event for each user on the same day and then calculates the total hours worked for each user per day.
Here's a generic example (we don't know you table name and data type details):
WITH EventPairs AS (
    SELECT
        resourcename,
        EventDateTime,
        AgentState,
        LAG(EventDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY resourcename, CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS PreviousEventDateTime,
        LAG(AgentState) OVER (PARTITION BY resourcename, CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS PreviousAgentState
    FROM
        your_table_name
),
WorkIntervals AS (
    SELECT
        resourcename,
        CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE) AS WorkDate,
        DATEDIFF('second', PreviousEventDateTime, EventDateTime) / 3600.0 AS HoursWorked
    FROM
        EventPairs
    WHERE
        AgentState = 'Logged Out' AND PreviousAgentState = 'Logged In'
)
SELECT
    resourcename,
    WorkDate,
    SUM(HoursWorked) AS TotalHoursWorked
FROM
    WorkIntervals
GROUP BY
    resourcename,
    WorkDate
ORDER BY
    resourcename,
    WorkDate;

The result of the query will be a table showing the total hours worked by each user per day. For the provided dataset, it would look something like this:
resourcename    WorkDate    TotalHoursWorked
Chris Medina    2024-05-06  10.12
Christie Willis 2024-05-06  8.77


Another way I can think of is lateral with left join to get logout timestamp and then find out hours (in seconds) spent for respective session. I haven't tested the query but should work, there can be typo tho. below is the query you can try.
select user_login.resourcename as resource_name
        , user_login.eventdatetime::date as work_date
        , to_time(to_timestamp
                    (sum(datediff(seconds, user_login.eventdatetime
                            -- curren time if user is still logged in and there is no logout entry
                            , nvl(user_logout.eventdatetime, current_timestamp))))
          ) as  total_hours_spent_hh_mm_ss
from user_login_info user_login
left join lateral
(
    select min(user_logout.eventdatetime) as eventdatetime
    from user_login_info user_logout
    where user_logout.resourcename = user_login.resourcename
            and user_logout.eventdatetime > user_login.eventdatetime
            and user_logout.agentstate = 'Logged Out'
) as user_logout
where user_login.agentstate = 'Logged In'
group by all;

